# What does $f(a,b)$ mean?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Trying to figure out if these are $true$ or $false$. But I don't get what $f(a,b)$ and $\exists f:$ stands for.

Is $\exists f:$ stands for functions exists in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$?

and

$f(a,b)$ stands for function of range from $a$ to $b$?

1. $\exists f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\implies \mathbb{R} \cdot \left( \log_{a \cdot b}\left( c\right) = \left(\log_a\left(c\right)\right)^{f(a,b)} \right)$
2. $\exists f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\implies \mathbb{R} \cdot \left( \log_{a \cdot b}\left( c\right) = \left({f(a,b)}\cdot\log_a\left(c\right)\right) \right)$

any other example that can help me understand this problem.

Comment: Corret; it means: "there is a real-valued function $f$ with two real arguments".

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^2\mapsto \mathbb{R}$, input ordered pair $(a,b)$ output a real number

Answer (score 1):

Yes in this case $\exists f$ stands for at least a function $f:\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ exists and $f(a,b)$ is the value for $f$ at the point $(x_1,x_2)=(a,b)$.

Answer (score 0):

> $\exists f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R} \cdot \left( \log_{a \cdot b}\left( c\right) = \left(\log_a\left(c\right)\right)^{f(a,b)} \right)$

This means that there exists a function $f$ of two variables on the real numbers such that $$ \log_{a \cdot b}\left( c\right) =
\left(\log_a\left(c\right)\right)^{f(a,b)} $$ where $a$ and $b$ are presumably previously defined real parameters, and $f(a,b)$ is the image of the ordered pair $(a,b)$ under $f$.

Similarly for your second example.